# "I am undecided between X and Y" - Expression

Tags: expression

Let us say you are buying something and talking with the seller behind the counter. How would you express your indecision between two items?

Is "Ich bin zwischen dem X und der Y" correct?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are missing the adjective:

> "Ich bin *unentschlossen* zwischen X und Y."

Alternatively:

> "Ich kann mich nicht zwischen X und Y entscheiden."
>
> "Ich weiß nicht, ob ich X oder Y nehmen soll."

Comment: Alright. In English am pretty sure the "I am between X and Y" expression would be understood. Is this the case too with "Ich bin zwischen X und Y" in German?

Comment: Yes, it would be understood, but it's incorrect grammar.

Comment: @keine... I'd actually say that someone who has no contact with English might not get what you mean unless there is a LOT of non verbal context.

Comment: If you are in the store in front of the counter it is pretty obvious.

Comment: If you don't have the two items with you then I am pretty sure that some clerk in a small town might not know what you want and figure you're trying to talk about location. Obviously, we can't tell, I just want to strongly recommend AGAINST using the phrase just for convenience under the assumption that everybody gets it.

Answer (score 7):

Also possible:

> "Ich schwanke zwischen X und Y."

Comment: Das ist mein Favorit!